# Turn this haml snippet into a helper to DRY up Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

This bit of haml works:

```
%select{ :name => 'color', :value => @p.color}
  - Person.color.options[:flags].each do |colors|
    - if @p.color == colors
      %option{:value => colors, :selected => "selected"}= colors
    - else
       %option{:value => colors}= colors
```

I'm trying to create a helper out of it so I can reuse it:

```
helpers do
  def options(prop, p)
    Person.prop.options[:flags].each do |x|
      if p.prop == x
        "%option{:value => #{x}, :selected => 'selected'}= #{x}"
      else
        "%option{:value => #{x}}= #{x}"
      end  
    end
  end
end
```

And then calling it with:

```
%select{ :name => 'color', :value => @p.color}
  - options(color, @p)
```

But I'm getting this error: `undefined local variable or method 'color'`

Am I far off?

**EDIT 2:**

Something funky is going on with the loop.

Even a simple example such as this:

```
helpers do
  def options(prop, p)
    Person.send(prop).options[:flags].each do |x|
    "<p>test</p>"
    end
  end
end
```

and `= options(:color, @p)`

prints an array of the options ( in my case `[:red, :blue, :yellow]`) and does not insert any html. However, if I do `puts <p>test</p>` it does go through the loop three times and prints them correctly—they just don't show up in the html.

Comment: I’ve updated my answer in response to your (deleted?) comment about `=` just inserting an array. It’s due to the helper returning the value of `each` rather than the string you want, which I overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a symbol instead of undefined method:

```
options(:color, @p)
```

instead of:

```
options(color, @p)
```

and on helper method use `send`:

```
if p.send(prop) == x
```

instead of

```
if p.prop == x
```

as well as:

```
Person.send(prop)
```

instead of:

```
Person.prop
```

Also, i'm in doubt HAML will accept a string like `"%option{:value => #{x}"` as a tag.

You can use HTML instead or just find another way to DRY, like render a partial or use `haml_tag`:

```
def options(prop, p)
  Person.send(prop).options[:flags].each do |x|
    haml_tag :option, "#{x}", :value=>x
  end
end
```

If you use `haml_tag` call it with `- options(:color, @p)`

Comment: Almost working. With some `puts`s I've found it is going through the loop, but the html isn't getting inserted. Do I need to do anything besides put it in quotes? `"<option value='#{x}'>#{x}</option>"` is what I've got. Thanks.

Comment: @bookcasey, `- options` will just execute the code without actually output anything. use `= options` instead. also, as i mentioned in the answer, `"%option` wont work with HAML. you could either put HTML directly, like `"<option value..."` or use `html_tag :option, :value => ...` to have HTML generated

Comment: @silvu, Thanks! However, now the only thing that makes it the html is an array of the different options. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @bookcasey, inside `options` method use `haml_tag :option` and call it like `- options(:color, @p)` in your HAML file

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things going on here. First, the message `undefined local variable or method 'color'` is caused by the line

```
- options(color, @p)
```

in your Haml. Here `color` is the undefined local variable. If I understand correctly you have a `Person` class that has various properties, each of which has several possible options and you want to be able to choose which one to use without hardcoding it and needing several helpers method. One way to do that would be to change the line

```
Person.prop.options[:flags].each do |x|
```

in your helper to

```
Person.send(prop).options[:flags].each do |x|
```

and then pass a symbol specifying the property to use when you call the helper:

```
- options(:color, @p)
```

The next problem is writing the generated code to the output. Your helper can either return a string which you can include with `=`, or it can write directly to the output using helpers like [`haml_tag`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#haml_tag-instance_method) and [`haml_concat`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#haml_concat-instance_method). Note that you shouldn’t use the return value of `haml_tag` or `haml_concat`, it will generate an error.

So here you can either create the HTML in the helper:

```
if p.prop == x
  "<option value='#{x}' selected='selected'>#{x}</option>"
else
  "<option value='#{x}' />#{x}</option>"
end
```

and then use it with `=` (if you use `-` the output will get ignored):

```
= options(:color, @p)
```

If you do this you need to make sure the helper returns the string you want to embed in your Haml. In this case the helper returns the value the call to `each`, [which is the array itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each). You need to use something like `map` and `join` to create the desired string:

```
def options(prop, p)
  Person.send(prop).options[:flags].map do |x|
    if p.prop == x
      "<option value='#{x}' selected='selected'>#{x}</option>"
    else
      "<option value='#{x}' />#{x}</option>"
    end
  end.join("\n")
end
```

The alternative is to use `haml_tag` to write the output directly.

```
if p.prop == x
  haml_tag :option, x, :value=>x, :selected => true
else
  haml_tag :option, x, :value =>x
end
```

Note that in Haml, any entry in an [attribute hash that has a boolean value](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#boolean_attributes) will only be output if the value is `true`, and it will be formatted correctly depending on the output, e.g. `selected='selected'` got XHTML and just `selected` for HTML. So this last example can be simplified to

```
haml_tag :option, x, :value=>x, :selected => (p.prop == x)
```

(You could always simplify the other example (returning a string) in a similar manner, with something like `#{"selected='selected'" if p.prop == x}`, but Haml has it built in.)